# Only insert in table when it meets certain condition from another table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, mamp

I have table called `Create_Group`. I would like to add a constraint that only people with user_type staff can insert in the table `Create_group`.

```
 CREATE TABLE `User` 
 ( 
      `user_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,    
      `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
      `user_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
      CONSTRAINT UC_User UNIQUE (user_id,username)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  


ALTER TABLE `User` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
```

I have tried doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Create_Group` 
(  
     `group_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
     `user_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
     `group_creator` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
     `group_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
     CONSTRAINT UC_Group UNIQUE (group_id,group_name)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

ALTER TABLE `Create_Group` 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),  
    ADD KEY (`user_id`); 

UPDATE `Create_Group`   
SET `group_id`,`user_id`,`group_creator`,`group_name`,`date_created`  
WHERE (SELECT user_type  
       FROM User  
       WHERE `group_creator`=username) = `Staff`
```

However the update keeps giving me an error.

Example of input for User:

```
INSERT INTO `User` (`user_id`, `username`, `user_type`)   
VALUES (UUID(), 'TheDoctor', 'Staff'), (UUID(), 'DoctorStrange', 'User');
```

Example of input for `Group_Create`:

```
INSERT INTO `Create_Group` (`group_id`, `user_id`, `group_creator`, `group_name`, `date_created`)   
    SELECT 
        UUID(),user_id,'TheDoctor','HeroesUnited', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  
    FROM 
        User  
    WHERE 
        username='TheDoctor'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using special character ` with every table name and column name? Also what is error you are getting? Please tag correct database SQL server, msAccess... etc in  this question

Answer (score 0):

Whichever SQL database you might be using. This Update seems incorrect, as no value is being assigned to it

Following seems incorrect

```
UPDATE `Create_Group`   
SET `group_id`,`user_id`,`group_creator`,`group_name`,`date_created`  
WHERE (SELECT user_type  
       FROM User  
       WHERE `group_creator`=username) = `Staff`
```

Try assigning some value to fields in SET like:

Note this is just example of how to correct the update query:

```
UPDATE `Create_Group`   
SET `group_id` = '1',`user_id` = '2',`group_creator`='3',`group_name`='name',`date_created`='2017-01-01'  
WHERE (SELECT user_type  
       FROM User  
       WHERE `group_creator`=username) = `Staff`
```

Also you should take care of the WHERE clause query. If more than 1 records will be returned by subquery

```
(SELECT user_type FROM User WHERE group_creator=username)
```

then the update will fail with error

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression